# Exporting interface which is extended

Tags: typescript, interface, export

I have interface `Person` in which I added another property (see example below).

I want to export it, however I ger error `'Person' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`.

```js
// test.d.ts
interface Person {
  age: number,
  name: string
}

interface Person {
  canCode: boolean
}

export Person // => 'Person' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

```js
// test.ts
import { Person } from './test' // => Module '"./test"' declares 'Person' locally, but it is not exported.

const myPerson: Person = {
  age: 17,
  name: 'Roman',
  canCode: true
}
```

Can you tell me please, how to fix it?

#### Additional info

Lang: `typescript@4.1.2`

Editor: `atom@1.53.0`

Editor Typescript package: `atom-typescript@14.1.2` (which is using `typescript@4.0.3`)

Also I checked all the code and suggestions in the VSC and the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `export` keyword on its own expects a value to export, but as you mentioned, `Person` is only a type.

To solve this, you simply just use `export interface`.

```
export interface Person { ... }
```

The interface (identified by its name) is now exported. You can perform further declaration merging by adding for example:

```
export interface Person { age: number }
interface Person { name: string }
```

Person will be merged together and exported as a single interface from the module.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. i am not extending interface via extend (to create new interface), but adding properties to the same interface. If I add `export` keyword before each of the interface Person shown in the example above, it will throw error `Module '"./test"' declares 'Person' locally, but it is not exported.`

Comment: I see, realized we were talking about declaration merging. Edited my answer accordlingly.

I'm not sure why TypeScript is complaining about the module declaring it locally yet not exporting it. Adding export to one or more of the items works fine for me locally on TypeScript 4.1.1

Comment: What is your TS version? I'm still unable to recreate, I'm using the following code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEEsBsFNQEYDoAmSAuBnAULAHgA4D2ATuqJAHbqwkBmAhgMbwCqmtoA3qJQwLawAXKEzoSVAOYAaUA0nDeAV34JOAX1yFS5KjXrM2HEt1AkicEWImVJoTdhAQY8BhhyR+xMqfYbQdOb8oADkSMAIIdhMRJRioErGIn4mALym8ooAjLJ8giIARACCBbLmlqAFCAX2QA

Comment: Please see updated post's Additional info section.